# Google Page Speed Insights shows zero cumulative layout shift with lab data, but poor CLS with field data

Tags: seo, google, page-speed, cumulative-layout-shift, core-web-vitals

Lab data, as well as online analysis tools show my site to have 0 cumulative layout shift (CLS) issues in mobile and desktop versions. However, Google field data is showing 0.30 CLS issues, (Critical, no passing level!).

Is this to be expected and typical? I have no other ideas on how to fix this. I wonder how  people can still experience CLS.... perhaps they are on older devices that don't respond to modern code, therefore having CLS issues?

Comment: Have you used Google Chrome's Lighthouse developer tools to test your site yourself with a variety of screen widths?   The lab data from Pagespeed Insights only uses two widths: one for desktop and one for mobile.  It is possible that there is some layout shift at another browser width.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, are you saying that Lighthouse tests CLS across all resolutions in a single step or that you can simply change the viewport and retest?

Comment: Using the Chrome developer tools you can change the viewport and rerun the lighthouse tests yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Is this to be expected and typical? In short, yes.

Google's extensive documentation on Core Web Vitals, and specifically on cumulative layout shift, are explicit on this point:

> **Caution:** Lab tools typically load pages in a synthetic environment and are thus only able to measure layout shifts that occur during page load. As a result, CLS values reported by lab tools for a given page may be less than what real users experience in the field.

Source: https://web.dev/cls/

> […]  while testing in the lab is a reasonable proxy for performance, it isn't necessarily reflective of how all users experience your site in the wild.

Source: https://web.dev/user-centric-performance-metrics/#in-the-field

Your "lab" measurements are useful up to a point, but the *real* measurement is the aggregated, real-world experiential data coming from CrUX (Chrome User Experience Report).